# setTimeout не отрабатывает

Tags: javascript, settimeout

```
    document.location.href = '/home';
    console.log('before');
    document.onload = function(){
    setTimeout(function(){
      console.log('fancy')}, 30000);
          };
   console.log('after');
```

в консоли:

```
before
after
XHR finished loading: GET "https://-------/home".
Navigated to https://------/home
```

После редиректа setTimeout не работает, ищу совета. Вместо  document.onload = function()... просто setTimout тоже к консоль не пишет.

Comment: Вы редирект те на другой документ и хотите что то увидеть на старой?

Comment: ` document.location.href` открывает новую страницу, где виртуальная машина javascript стартует с нуля и ничего не знает о процессах, запущенных на предыдущей странице. Какую логику вы вкладываете в это ожидание по таймауту?

Comment: @Aziz Umarov не скажете как поступить, чтоб он был на новой? Ожидал, что после редиректа будет новая.

Comment: @renich после редиректа мне нужно открыть попап funcybox. Так и понял что страницу потерял, но как остаться на новой после редиректа?

Comment: @trollDemiurg добавил в ответ

Answer (score 2):

Когда загружается новая страница, браузер уже не помнит, что было запущено на предыдущей. Один из вариантов решения:

Вместо /home, направить на адрес с каким-нибудь параметром:

`document.location.href = '/home?l=0';`

И уже на home заранее подготовить скрипт,

```
let fn_storage = {
  "0": function() {
    console.log("code ?l=0");
  },

  "moo": function() {
    console.log("code ?l=moo");
  },
};

let key = ( window.location.search.match(/l=(.*?)(&|$)/) || [0,0] )[1];
if (key) setTimeout(fn_storage[key], 5000);
```

---

Еще, можно использовать [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage), [sessionStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage)

Comment: Да блин все равно обрабатывать скриптом на той странице. Тогда уж onload спокойно использовать

Comment: @AzizUmarov Ну вопрос в передаче информации с одной страницы на другую... Пример можно завернуть и в onload)

Comment: Передача информации думаю совсем другая задача. Если посмотреть заголовок то вообще что по чем ))

Comment: @OPTIMUS PRIME спасибо, через параметр решил.

Answer (score 0):

Вы редиректите страницу а на старой поставили setTimeout(...); Что вы хотите увидеть она даже если и загрузилась ее уже нет к тому времени.

Если вы хотите запустить скрипт на новой странице. Это будет делать та самая страница и ее скрипт либо делайте как все SPA подгружаете контент и обрабатываете.

Вон подкатили ответ снизу.

Answer (score 0):

Можно реализовать загрузку и подмену контента, по аналогии с SPA (Single Page Application).

```js
console.log('before');
let destination = "/home";
fetch(destination).then((response) => response.ok && response.text().then((html) => {
    window.history.pushState({}, "", destination);
    document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML = html;
    setTimeout(() => {
        console.log('fancy')
    }, 30000);
}));
console.log('after');
```